# %matplotlib notebook showing a blank histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

In my Jupyter notebook I am now using `%matplotlib notebook` instead of `%matplotlib inline`, it's awesome that I can now interact with my plots on Jupyter. However, when I try to make an histogram I get a blank plot:

[image: %matplotlib notebook]

If I use `%matplotlib inline` everything works fine:
[image: %matplotlib inline]

What's going on?

Comment: If you right-click where it should be and Inspect the page, is there a `<div>` there? Are there any Javascript errors?

Comment: @NickT I don't get the usual `<div style="display: inline-block">` that I get with other successful plots. I get no Javascript errors.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, for me it's working fine on python 2.7, jupyter server 4.0.6, IPython 4.0. (I tried it in under Windows using Firefox 50 and Opera 41). Maybe it's still worthwhile to produce a [MCVE], such that people are testing the same code.

Comment: I see a bit clearer. I think it has something to do with changing on the fly between `%matplotlib notebook` and `%matplotlib inline`. Try to create a new notebook and use it there.

Comment: I had the same problem, @ImportanceOfBeingErnest 's reply did the trick for me - I was switching from %matplotlib inline to %matplotlib notebook and getting the same blank plot - then I restarted the notebook and used notebook from the get go, and the plots appear correctly.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Seeing that my comment above has indeed helped someone to solve the problem I will post it as an answer.

The problem occurs if you switch from `%matplotlib inline` to `%matplotlib notebook` without restarting the kernel.

Switching from `%matplotlib notebook` to `%matplotlib inline` works fine.

So the solution is to either restart the kernel or start a new notebook.

It seems that in some cases it helps to repeat the setting of the notebook backend, i.e. call it twice like

```
%matplotlib notebook
%matplotlib notebook
```

An analysis for why that is can be found in [this comment](https://github.com/shoeffner/cvloop/issues/20#issuecomment-340292628)

Comment: calling `%matplotlib notebook' before import matplotlib solved the issue for me

Comment: is this possibly fixed in any newer version of the involved packages?

Comment: @matanster Not that I know of and the linked issue is still open, but I have found that the repeated statement works quite reliably.

Answer (score 12):

The answer is not necessarily to restart the entire kernel.

If you reload the matplotlib module, it will work, too. Provided you use Python 3.6 like me, and you have `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` like me:

```
from importlib import reload
reload(plt)
%matplotlib notebook
```

It does the trick. Yes it is still a hack. At least this is an independent codecell you can use in the middle of the notebook. Switching back via `%matplotlib inline` is not a problem.

You can also remove once imported names from the sys.modules list, then they get imported again when you call the import again.

```
import sys
sys.modules.pop('matplotlib')
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

In many cases, that's a less good idea. But it might sometimes be the only straw to hold on.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it by downgrading matplotlib to 3.1.3:

```
conda install matplotlib=3.1.3
```

I was running version 3.3.2 and had this same issue. I was not switching between `%matplotlib inline` and `%matplotlib notebook`, and it did not matter if I placed `%matplotlib notebook` before or after importing

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be an interaction between switching:

```
%matplotlib notebook
%matplotlib inline
```

and using the figure "power button" on interactive plots:

[image]

**Solution**: If you pressed the button and are getting blank plots, restart Jupyter and **don't use the power button again** if you need to switch between `notebook` and `inline`

Answer (score 0):

On a new notebook if you start by using %matplotlib notebook then you can switch between that an inline without issue.
I confirm that both restarting of the kernel and the running of the code do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

For me, it also appeared after switching from 'inline' to 'notebook' but restarting the kernel didn't work. I had to go through file > close and halt, and then either reopen it or restart the kernel if the page is still open.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into the blank plots issue.
Funny enough, I find there are two different ways to fix it and I have not yet discovered why I need one method and when the other.

**Method 1:**

Start a cell like so:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.ion()
```

Then in the next cell type:

```
plt.hist([3,8,10])
```

In most cases the plot will appear in its own window, unless you are using the `%matplotlib inline` at the top of the cell (which I never do, I like to manipulate the plots).

**Method 2:**

However, sometimes (not sure why), method 1 does not work even after a kernel restart (not sure why yet).

You may see a little window appear that does not show the plot but remains blank (as before), but this time you hover over it with the mouse, you'll get the "thinking" icon.

In that case remove any `plt.show()` and add the following at the end of the cell:

```
plt.pause(1)
```

This should show the plots in the figures and they should be responsive too.

Good luck!

Tested on:

```
Windows 10
jupyter running inside Visual Studio Code 1.83.1
jupyter_client==8.6.0
jupyter_core==5.7.1
jupyterlab_widgets==3.0.10
python 3.10.13
matplotlib 3.8.2
```