# Matplotlib plots not showing on Jupyter Notebook when I 'run all'

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

The plots are not displayed inline in notebooks when using `matplotlib`

The plots appear completely blank. Any ideas?

[image: seen here]

Comment: This happened me once. Are you importing matplotlib and pyplot? Or just using `%matplotlib notebook` . In my case I had to import them too.

Comment: Could it be that you try to switch the backend in the middle of the notebook? (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41125690/matplotlib-notebook-showing-a-blank-histogram))

Comment: I'm getting this fairly often too and the cause isn't anything obvious to me.  No multiple switching backends or simple failure to import.  The problem is **intermittent**.  Often just running the cell again will cause the figure to show up.  Also, sometimes saving the figure (via the button) returns a blank figure too.  Really odd and annoying.

Comment: Also... Happens under Firefox and Chrome.  Restart and Run All seems to be screw up more than running individual cells (no, it isn't because Run All is hitting an error before rendering).

Comment: For me `matplotlib.pyplot.show()` works.

Answer (score 46):

Came across the same issue on calling "Restart & Run all". Following this

[%matplotlib notebook showing a blank histogram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41125690/matplotlib-notebook-showing-a-blank-histogram?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I could resolve the issue adding

```
%matplotlib inline
```

at the beginning of the cell. Also note that you can prevent string output by adding `;` to the end of a line.

Comment: this should be accepted answer

Comment: adding the %matplotlib inline didn't solve my problem with Sagemaker notebooks

Answer (score 5):

I faced a similar issue with my Chrome Browser, whereas it works fine with Mozilla.

%matplotlib inline will lead to static images of your plot embedded in the notebook, so that cannot be the solution for this prevailing issue.

Comment: Your pointer towards trying a different browser saved my sanity, thanks... Still don't know why this happens though.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue - %matplotlib notebook command would not display the plot but %matplotlib inline would. Had to downgrade matplotlib version from 3.1.3 to 3.1.2.

Python 3.7.9, conda 4.5.11

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to create a graph using the Object-Oriented Interface try adding

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
```

above your `ax.plot`

Answer (score 0):

Having the whole snippet in the same cell solves this issue. This means that first you add %matplotlib inline in one cell. Run it. Then you add all the elements of the figure, axes and all in the same cell, then run it. It shows the chart perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I find inconsistent behaviour, but any of the following 2 methods should work:

**Method 1**
Start a cell like so:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.ion()
```

Then in the next cell type:

```
plt.hist([3,8,10])
```

In most cases the plot will appear in its own window.

**Method 2**
However, sometimes (not sure why), this does not work even after a kernel restart.

You may see a little window appear that does not show the plot but remains blank and if you hover over it with the mouse, you'll get the "thinking" icon.

In that case end your plotting cell like so:

```
plt.pause(1)
```

This should show the plots in the figures and they should be responsive too.

Good luck!

Tested on:

```
Windows 10
jupyter running inside Visual Studio Code 1.83.1
jupyter_client==8.6.0
jupyter_core==5.7.1
jupyterlab_widgets==3.0.10
python 3.10.13
matplotlib 3.8.2
```

Answer (score -1):

In case you do not have any output after running the cell, make sure that the cell is a code cell - In my case the cell was mistakenly turned into a 'raw' cell.