# My jupyter notebook plots aren't displayed

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I’m using an Advertising Dataset for linear Regression. I am doing Exploratory Data Analysis on data while doing so i am not getting graph displayed in Jupytor Notebook.
both boxplot and sns,pairplot ,sns.distplot not showing graph in jupyter notebook

```py
data.boxplot(column="Newspaper Ad Budget ($)")

sns.pairplot(data,x_vars=["TV Ad Budget ($)","Radio Ad Budget ($)","Newspaper Ad Budget ($)"],y_vars="Sales ($)",kind="reg")

sns.distplot(Y,hist=True)
```

Comment: First, review how to post code here, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/51144). What you have supplied is unusable and unreadable. I believe there is a button you can use in the editor to enter code. Second, does it trigger making any whitespace in the output area when you run the currently unreadable code? Third, do [the Seaborn examples](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/index.html) work?

Comment: Update seaborn. The current version is 0.13 and distplot was removed.

Comment: Question needs a complete [mre] with sample data posted as text.

Comment: Maybe you need to add something like `%matplotlib inline` or `%matplotlib qtagg`?

Comment: @JohanC As an FYI neither of those are needed in current versions of Jupyter Notebook (which shouldn't be used because it's old), or Jupyter Lab (which should be used because this is updated to modern web technology). Though, based on their use of `distplot` they may be in an ooold version.

Comment: Upvoting a question lacking a complete [mre] just because they user is new, is a form of voter targeting, which is discouraged. The point of voting is to show a questions / answers value to the community, not to applaud someone new for posting a question. **Upvote:** _The question shows research effort; it is useful and clear_.

Comment: Duplicates [Matplotlib plots not showing on Jupyter Notebook when I 'run all'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47507830/7758804), [Plots not showing in Jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61128143/7758804)

Comment: can you try adding this as the first line of your code in jupyter notebook and see if anything changes, update me accordingly for further help: %matplotlib inline          also maybe check if the packages you are using are outdated?