# Switching between 'widget' and 'inline' matplotlib backends in Jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

This is a question I've been meaning to ask for quite some time and always postponed.

In a Jupyter notebook (v6.0.1) I constantly find myself having to switch backends between `%matplotlib inline` and `%matplotlib widget` (i.e.  [ipympl](https://github.com/matplotlib/jupyter-matplotlib)). Whenever I go from `inline` to `widget`, I have to run the cell several times and, somehow, "with the right timing", so that the backend actually kicks in. Any ideas as to why?

Comment: This is most probably the same issue as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41125690/matplotlib-notebook-showing-a-blank-histogram).

Comment: Not quite, I don't get a blank plot but rather `inline` is returned even though I called for `widget` (or `notebook`) - which I do twice as suggested. Of course it works fine if the kernel is restarted, but that kind of nullifies the whole idea of being able to switch backends...

Comment: No sure, but it's the same underlying issue (which would answer the question as to *why*).