# Animation shows only a static picture - jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter, matplotlib-animation

I found an interesting animation of a [particle system](https://github.com/xnx/collision) that I would like to implement on jupyter notebook. So I copied the code in the file [collision.py](https://github.com/xnx/collision/blob/master/collision.py) and pasted it on my jupyter notebook. After executing the code I am getting only a static picture

[image]

I tried to include the magic command %matplotlib inline but it still does not work. Does someone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run the code you showed, `collision.mp4` will be saved locally and I can play it as an animation.
If you want to run the animation in jupyter environment, you need to install the following code.

```
# Jupyter lab
from IPython.display import HTML
%matplotlib inline

(Omission)

# plt.show()

# jupyter lab 
plt.close()
HTML(anim.to_html5_video())
```

This is just one example of what I do. Please try [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25333732/matplotlib-animation-not-working-in-ipython-notebook-blank-plot) as it is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You need to save it as a **gif file**. Then open it in **jupyter notebook**

Comment: I don't know Jupyter notebook but I highly doubt that this is the only way to use FuncAnimation.