# Getting two graphs using matplotlib animation instead of one

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, geopandas, matplotlib-animation

I am trying to plot world population map using geopandas and matplotlib. I also use matplotlib animation to make graph animated for each year.

```
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from IPython.display import HTML


fig,ax=plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(15,5))

def animation_bar(year):
    filtered=df[df['Year']==year]  
    filtered.plot(ax=ax,column='Population',cmap='Reds',scheme='quantiles')
    ax.set_title(int(year),fontweight='bold')
    
animator=animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animation_bar,frames=sorted(df['Year'].unique()),interval=300)
HTML(animator.to_jshtml())
```

I get two graphs as an output:
[image]

One graph is animated as intended, second one is static. One more concern about the output is that, the graph is smaller. As seen in the code I wanted the figsize=(15,5). It should be bigger than it is. I can't increase its size.

**How to modify the code?**

Comment: Can you share the data required to plot this figure?

Comment: would you consider **plotly** as graphing library instead?

Comment: I think you're getting both the HTML widget and the matplotlib figure. If you do something along the lines of `widget = HTML(animator.to_jshtml()); fig.close(); widget` does that solve the problem?

Comment: @medium-dimensional, the very last code snippet of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46878070) can be used to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use `plt.close()` anywhere in between `plt.subplots` and `HTML(animator.to_jshtml())`.

For example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation
from IPython.display import HTML

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
l = ax.plot([0, 2], [0, 3])[0]
t = [0, 1, 2]
x = [2, 0, 3]
animate = lambda n: l.set_data(t[:n+2], x[:n+2])
ani = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=2)

plt.close()  # here it is!
HTML(ani.to_jshtml())
```

[image]

Comment: But it'd be interesting to also know: 1) **Why** this solves the problem. 2) Why this problem happens in the first place. 3) And any other maybe more appropriate methods to solve it.